# Can Misty Escape be used out of combat?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, combat, warlock

DnD 5e: What if my character is not in combat when using Misty Escape? For example, she could be imprisoned in a cell and use it to escape the cell. In that case, she teleports, but is not in combat when she rematerializes. Can she then stay invisible "Until she attacks or casts a spell?" "Until her next turn" is not applicable if she's not in combat.

A weird edge-case I can't find an answer for—unless the answer is "you can only use Misty Escape in combat," in which case the rest of the question is irrelevant.

Comment: Which feature for teleportation that isn't a spell is used in your idea?

Comment: Hi, Taliesin. I've approved the edit and reopened now that that's clarified, but you should go through the process of getting your two accounts [merged](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) so you can control your question (edits not requiring review, commenting on it, accepting an answer, etc.). No worries though, this happens from time to time and is usually a quick fix (see the link)

Answer (score 19):

#### You can use Misty Escape if you take damage.

Misty Escape states:

> When you take damage, you can use your reaction to turn invisible and teleport up to 60 feet to an unoccupied space you can see.

You can take damage out of combat, so there is no reason you cannot use Misty Escape out of combat.

#### “Until your next turn” is six seconds, because a round is six seconds long.

The rules for combat state:

> A round represents about 6 seconds in the game world. During a round, each participant in a battle takes a turn.

So when Misty Escape says:

> You remain invisible until the start of your next turn or until you attack or cast a spell.

It means that you stay invisible for the next six seconds.

#### You are able to take reactions outside of combat.

Just in case there is any question about taking a reaction outside of combat, I’ve copied my argument from [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/172581/62294)

As evidence of being able to take a reaction in response to a relevant trigger *outside of combat*, consider the spell [*feather fall*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/feather-fall):

> Choose up to five falling creatures within range. A falling creature's rate of descent slows to 60 feet per round until the spell ends. If the creature lands before the spell ends, it takes no falling damage and can land on its feet, and the spell ends for that creature.

*Feather fall* has a casting time of 1 Reaction,

> which you take when you or a creature within 60 feet of you falls.

I think it quite obvious that the act of falling does not initiate combat or require rolling initiative, and so there is a clear sense in which *feather fall* is intended to be usable outside of combat. Therefore, you have your reaction available *outside of combat*.

Comment: Some fight club vibes here